# Remove element from a cached jquery selection

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

This should'nt be that difficult but for some reason i'm having trouble with this.

I want to remove the first li from a cached ul:

```
var $selection = jQuery('.list').filter('.exclude');
```

.

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="exclude" >Do not Include</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

How do I capture the **entire** ul object without the first child li element in it?

Thanks

EDIT: 
The resulting jquery object i'm looking for is:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Not this:

```
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "capture the entire ul"? Are you trying to create `$selection` as a jQuery object containing just the li elements that don't have the "exclude" class? Or should the jQuery object also contain the ul element itself?

Comment: Jquery object with Ul element itself. I want it to return a UL excluding a specific child LI.. In other words i dont want it to return just a orphaned LI elements.. hope that make sense?

Comment: Actually, no, it didn't quite make sense. If you say `jQuery(".list")` you'll get a jQuery object with exactly one element in it, the ul element - note that this is a _reference_ to the actual DOM element, so you can still use traversal methods to get to the associated li elements, but none of the li elements will be in the jQuery object itself. If you want the jQuery object to contain the ul element and the lis (except the "exclude" one) you can say `jQuery(".list,.list li:not(.exclude)")` or `jQuery(".list").add(".list li:not(.exclude)")`.

Comment: Just tried it your suggested solutions.. they both return the the original ul with li elements (indeed excluding .exclude) appended *outside* the ul.. not the result i'm looking for.. i'm going edit my question a little.. i see now that i did a poor job at explaining what i wanted.. my apologies.

Comment: Are you trying to update what is displayed on the page by actually removing the "exclude" element? Or make a copy of the original list and append the copy to the page so that you see two lists at once (one with three li elements and one with two)? I'm still confused because what you're describing as a "jQuery object" is actually more like an html fragment...

Comment: yea i'm really new to javascript and jquery so i apologize for the confusion.. Thanks a million for your input!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/onidus/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
var $selection = jQuery('.list li').not('.exclude');
```

(You were close:) Using the `.not()` (or `:not`) selector and `$('.list li')` elements collection (to be filtered)

---

`$('.list li').remove('.exclude');`

**[demo](http://jsbin.com/onidus/2/edit)**

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/not

Comment: This does work well and I was actually able to solve my problem... However, i'm still curious..  how do i get it to return the entire ul.
So i want to grab the entire ul like this: `jQuery('.list')` then remove the first child (.exclude) and return the entire ul

Comment: @JoseBrowne `$('.list li').remove('.exclude');` DEMO: http://jsbin.com/onidus/2/edit Sorry I did not see your late edit.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/9NtLF =)

```
var list = $("ul.list").clone();
list.find("li.exclude").remove();
```